# How to transform a column with multiple numbers into a series of dummy variables?

Tags: database, excel, transformation

I need to transform some data for import into a relational database. In the database entity, there is a series of 21 yes/no variables. In the current format, there is a single column with a series of numbers, separated by spaces, each one corresponding to a "yes" for that variable.

For example, the column might read "3 7 12 20", which would correspond to "Yes" for variables 3, 7, 12, and 20, and "No" for all others.

I need to transform that column into the dummy variable format. I know I can use the "Text to Columns" tool in excel to separate the numbers in the column. But that's as far as I've gotten. How can I tell the software that a numerical column corresponds to a certain value for a certain column?

I am hoping to do this in Excel but also have beginning proficiency in SQL and Stata.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it in Excel.  If you have the current data in column `A` starting at `A2`, and the numbers 1 to 21 in `B1:V1`, then enter the formula below in `B2` and fill down and right as needed:

```
=OR(NOT(ISERROR(FIND(" " & B$1& " ",$A2))),LEFT($A2,LEN(B$1)+1)=TEXT(B$1,"@") & " ",RIGHT($A2,LEN(B$1)+1)=" " & TEXT(B$1,"@"),TRIM($A2)=TEXT(B$1,"@"))
```

This tests for one of four conditions:

1. The value we are looking for (i.e. the one from the relevant column
   in the first row), with a space either side, can be found in the
   cell in column A (`FIND(" " & B$1& " ",$A2)` is not an error); or
2. The value we are looking for, plus a trailing space (`TEXT(B$1,"@") & " "`) is the first thing in the cell in column A (`LEFT($A2,LEN(B$1)+1)`); or
3. The value we are looking for, plus a leading space, is the last thing in the cell in column A.
4. The value we are looking for is the only thing in the cell in column A.

Comment: This works perfectly when there is more than one number in the cell in column A, but it seems to be failing when there is only one number. For example, if the cell in column A reads "1 10", then the appropriate columns show "TRUE". However, if the column just reads "1" or "10", then the appropriate column does not show "TRUE". I tried to decipher the formula and make a couple edits, but couldn't find a fix. Any thoughts on why this might be happening? Thanks!

Comment: Never mind, figured it out! I just added ',$A2=B$1' to the end of the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Though you did not mention it, I wanted to supply a solution in R. Assume the following source data:

[image]

```
# Load the needed package, load the workbook containing the input data and read the sheet
library(xlsx) 
wb <- loadWorkbook(file="currentFormat.xlsx")
input <- read.xlsx(file="currentFormat.xlsx", sheetIndex=1, startRow=2, header=FALSE, colIndex=1)

# Number of individuals/observations/rows
N <- nrow(input)

# Prepare output data matrix
output <- matrix(0, ncol=21, nrow=N)

# Get 'Yes' answers for each i in N
true <- apply(X=input, 1,FUN=function(z) {as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(z, fixed = TRUE, split = " "))) } )

# Fill the output matrix
for(i in 1:N) {
  output[i, true[[i]]] <- 1
}

# Write output spreadsheet
write.xlsx(x = as.data.frame(output), file = "dummyData.xlsx", sheetName = "Output", row.names = TRUE)
```

The code is not very beautiful but it does want you are asking (I guess):
[image]